# c++: selectionSort with pointers instead of index

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, indexing

I want to sort numbers using pointers instead of indexes. By the way this is the header file :

```
int * sort(const int * const array, int size)
```

And below is the source code I was given

```
void selectionSort(int list[], int arraySize)
{
    for(int i=arraySize-1; i>=1; i--)
    {
       int currentMax=list[0];
       int currentMaxIndex=0;

       for(int j=1; j<=i; j++)
       {
          if(currentMax=list[j])
          {
             currentMax=list[i];
             currentMaxIndex=j;
          }
       }
       if(currentMaxIndex != i)
       {
          list[currentMaxIndex]=list[i];
          list[i]=currentMax;
       }
    }
}
```

I know you can switch list[i] to *(list+i) but I don't know how to do it with "currentMaxIndex". I'd really appreciate your help!!

Comment: if you mean how to do this: list[currentMaxIndex]=list[i]; . You can do it with this syntax: *(list+curMaxIdx) = *(list+i). They both do the same thing. I don't get why do you want to change the syntax!

Comment: You know that you can use `p[i]` syntax with pointers as well, not just with arrays, right?

Comment: @interjay I'm sorry but can you explain?

Comment: @Brahim I tried it but it keeps saying this [Error] assignment of read-only location '*(array + ((sizetype)(((long long unsigned int)currentMaxIndex) * 4ull)))'

Comment: ok, i think I get it. It's because list is an array which is equivalent to a constant pointer. try to declare list as int*.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers in C are integers like any others, and can be compared with the usual operations.

So you can do things like:

```
int *end = list + length; // Create a pointer to one-past the end of an array
for(int *it = list; it < end; it++){ /* use it to read the elements */ }
int *my_favorite_index = list + some_index;
```

I'm not going to solve your homework for you, but I hope this helps.